# docker run IMAGE /bin/bash does not work and return errors

Tags: python, bash, docker

Basically, I can't run a container with /bin/bash, and it is not returning any errors. I can run it with:

```
sudo docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash
```

and it works fine, I am able to get into the container and do stuff. However, the following does not work:

```
sudo docker run IMAGE-NAME /bin/bash
```

In the Dockerfile I have the following CMD command:

```
CMD [ "python3", "/opt/code/python-fire-server-base/main.py", "-v", "-H=0.0.0.0", "-p=9002", "-l=/tmp/python-fire-server-base.log", "-s", "/tmp/save/" ]
```

I know that the CMD is calling for a Python code, but previously (2-3 weeks ago), I was able to run the image created with this Dockerfile without issues using the `run` command. Now for some reason, it doesn't work, and it doesn't return any errors as well. I didn't change the Dockerfile, only modified the underlying Python code.

What am I missing here?

Edit:
Dockerfile is

```
# ----- First stage to build ismrmrd and siemens_to_ismrmrd -----
FROM python:3.10.2-slim AS mrd_converter
ARG  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV  TZ=America/Chicago

RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install -y git cmake g++ libhdf5-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libboost-all-dev libfftw3-dev libpugixml-dev
RUN  mkdir -p /opt/code

# Python Dependencies
WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
  && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


# ISMRMRD library
RUN cd /opt/code && \
    git clone https://github.com/ismrmrd/ismrmrd.git && \
    cd ismrmrd && \
    git checkout v1.13.4 && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake ../ && \
    make -j $(nproc) && \
    make install

# siemens_to_ismrmrd converter
RUN cd /opt/code && \
    git clone https://github.com/ismrmrd/siemens_to_ismrmrd.git && \
    cd siemens_to_ismrmrd && \
    git checkout v1.2.10 && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake ../ && \
    make -j $(nproc) && \
    make install

# Create archive of ISMRMRD libraries (including symlinks) for second stage
RUN cd /usr/local/lib && tar -czvf libismrmrd.tar.gz libismrmrd*

# ----- Start another clean build without all of the build dependencies of siemens_to_ismrmrd -----
#FROM ubuntu:20.04
#ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
FROM python:3.10.2-slim

LABEL org.opencontainers.image.description="Python MRD Image Reconstruction and Analysis Server"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.url="https://github.com/kspaceKelvin/python-fire-server-base"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.authors="Kelvin Chow (kelvin.chow@siemens-healthineers.com)"

# Copy ISMRMRD files from last stage
COPY --from=mrd_converter /usr/local/include/ismrmrd        /usr/local/include/ismrmrd/
COPY --from=mrd_converter /usr/local/share/ismrmrd          /usr/local/share/ismrmrd/
COPY --from=mrd_converter /usr/local/bin/ismrmrd*           /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=mrd_converter /usr/local/lib/libismrmrd.tar.gz  /usr/local/lib/
RUN cd /usr/local/lib && tar -zxvf libismrmrd.tar.gz && rm libismrmrd.tar.gz && ldconfig

# Copy siemens_to_ismrmrd from last stage
COPY --from=mrd_converter /usr/local/bin/siemens_to_ismrmrd  /usr/local/bin/siemens_to_ismrmrd

# xslt and hdf5 are dependencies for siemens_to_ismrmrd
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y libxslt1.1 libhdf5-103 git
RUN mkdir -p /opt/code

# Python MRD library
RUN pip3 install h5py ismrmrd==1.13.1

RUN  cd /opt/code \
     && git clone https://github.com/ismrmrd/ismrmrd-python-tools.git \
     && cd /opt/code/ismrmrd-python-tools \
     && pip3 install --no-cache-dir .

# matplotlib is used by rgb.py and provides various visualization tools including colormaps
# pydicom is used by dicom2mrd.py to parse DICOM data
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir matplotlib pydicom pynetdicom

# # If building from the GitHub repo, uncomment the below section, open a command
# # prompt in the folder containing this Dockerfile and run the command:
# #    docker build --no-cache -t kspacekelvin/fire-python ./
# RUN  cd /opt/code \
#      && git clone https://github.com/kspaceKelvin/python-fire-server-base.git

# If doing local development, use this section to copy local code into Docker
# image. From the folder containing the python-fire-server-base repo, uncomment
# the COPY line below and run the command:
#RUN docker build --no-cache -t fire-python-custom -f python-fire-server-base/docker/Dockerfile ./
RUN mkdir -p /opt/code/python-fire-server-base \
    && mkdir -p /opt/code/python-fire-server-base/doc \
    && mkdir -p /opt/code/python-fire-server-base/docker \
    && mkdir -p /opt/code/python-fire-server-base/.vscode .
COPY ./ /opt/code/python-fire-server-base


# Ensure startup scripts have Unix (LF) line endings, which may not be true
# if the git repo is cloned in Windows
RUN apt-get install -y dos2unix \
    && find /opt/code/python-fire-server-base -name *.sh | xargs dos2unix \
    && apt-get remove dos2unix -y

# Ensure startup scripts are marked as executable, which may be lost if files
# are copied in Windows
RUN find /opt/code/python-fire-server-base -name *.sh -exec chmod +x {} \;

# Cleanup files not required after installation
RUN  apt-get remove git -y \
     && apt-get clean \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
     && rm -rf /root/.cache/pip

# Set the starting directory so that code can use relative paths
WORKDIR /opt/code/python-fire-server-base

CMD [ "python3", "/opt/code/python-fire-server-base/main.py", "-v", "-H=0.0.0.0", "-p=9002", "-l=/tmp/python-fire-server-base.log", "-s", "/tmp/save/" ]

# Replace the above CMD with this ENTRYPOINT to allow allow "docker stop"
# commands to be passed to the server.  This is useful for deployments, but
# more annoying for development
# ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "/opt/code/python-fire-server-base/main.py", "-v", "-H=0.0.0.0", "-p=9002", "-l=/tmp/python-fire-server-base.log"]
```

Comment: `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash --rm IMAGE-NAME`

Comment: @larsks There is no ENTRYPOINT in the image, I will paste the Dockerfile as an edit

Comment: @Turing85 I misread your code. This is the correct answer, as Paolo also pointed out. Thank you I forgot the `-it` apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to allocate the pseudo-TTY:

```bash
sudo docker run -it IMAGE-NAME /bin/bash
```

this will overwrite the default `CMD` with `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Yeah, this was the reason, apparently. Thank you. I need to correct my notes as well.